# Remove ... and show all columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**df** is the database with 240 columns

```
 Col1   Col2 Col3  Col4 Col5  ...................Col239 Col240
```

Code

```
  [IN]df.columns
  [OUT] Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', .........'Col239', 'Col240'])
```

I want the names of all the columns and no ..... Could not find the solution for python pandas on stack overflow

Answer:

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

as mentioned in duplicate question also not working

Comment: This is a generic question with Col names at top. How to view all the columns rather than only few column names and then dots and then the last column names.

Comment: sorry wrongly understand